# Ionic 3 leaflet map position

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, leaflet

I've managed to use leaflet maps in ionic 3, but I have a problem with the positioning. I want a square map under all the text when scrolling.

I read something on how to use leaflet maps and I came across this sass.

```
.map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    }
```

this is the component html

```
<div class="map-container">
  <div #map id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  </div>
<div>
```

this is where I use the component

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)" *ngIf="event">

          <h1><b>{{event.title | uppercase }}</b></h1>

          <p>{{ event.custom_fields.evcal_srow*1000 | date: ' EEEE MMMM d' }}</p>

          <p><b>{{ event.custom_fields.evcal_srow*1000 | date:  'h:mm a' }} - {{ event.custom_fields.evcal_erow*1000 | date: 'h:mm a' }}</b></p>

          <p>{{event.content | removehtml }}</p>

          <map [data]="event"></map>

          <h1 (click)="AddToCalendar(event)">ADD TO CALENDAR</h1>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaZSa.png)

And when I change position absolute to anything else it just doesn't display.

How can I make the map just appear under the text?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo to reproduce it?

Comment: If it's css that is controlling your position I would use dev tools on chrome for ionic serve and determine the exact class that needs to be manipulated. This has helped me tons with certain components that needed style changes. Of course keep in mind that md is related to Android and ios of course is related to ios.

Answer (score 0):

You add Like this type of CSS

```
.map-container {
float:left;
position: relative;
float:left;
```

}